# Double orthogonal complement of a finite module

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules

Crossposted to [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/75262/double-orthogonal-complement-of-a-module)

Let $W$ be the finite $\mathbb{Z}$-module obtained from $\mathbb{Z}_q^n$ with addition componentwise. Let $V$ be a submodule of $W$. Let $V^{\perp} = \{w \in W \, : \, \forall v \in V \quad v.w = 0 \}$ where "." is the dot product. Is it true that ${(V^{\perp})}^{\perp} = V$?

Comment: I would use the notation $V^{\perp}$.

Comment: I don't think you waited long enough before crossposting. I would give it at least a day.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked and answered on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/75262/21564). I have replicated the accepted answer by Chris Godsil below.

> The answer is yes. The easiest way for me is to appeal to character theory. If $\zeta$ is
>   a complex $q$-th root of 1 then the map from $\mathbb{Z}_q^n$ to $\mathbb{C}$ given by
>   $$
>  x \mapsto \zeta^{a^Tx},\qquad (a\in\mathbb{Z}_q^n)
> $$
>   is a character of the abelian group $W=\mathbb{Z}_q^n$. The set of characters obtained as
>   $a$ varies over the elements of $W$ is the character group $W^*$ of $W$. 
>   If $V$ is a subgroup of $W$, then $V^\perp=V^*$ is isomorphic to the subgroup $(W/V)^*$ 
>   of $W^*$.
>
> A convenient source for the relevant character theory is from our own KConrad:  `http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/` (under characters of finite abelian groups).